# Select max value only when result values are different

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create query to count prices with same value and from this set I want to fetch one with max value of previous counting e.g for.

- 3 x 10$
- 10 x 20$

max will be 10, because price with value 20$ occurs 10 times in table. To do that I created a query like below:

```
SELECT price_count, subquery.value
FROM (SELECT COUNT(price_entity.value) price_count, price_entity.value
  FROM price_entity
           inner join purchasing_centre_entity pce on price_entity.purchasing_centre_id = pce.id
  where price_entity.purchasing_centre_id = 1
    and price_entity.product_id = 1
    and price_entity.create_date = DATE('2020-09-11')
  GROUP BY price_entity.value
 ) as subquery;
```

The problem occurs in case when I have same amount of counted prices. In this case I'd like to have empty result because I don't want two max results.

[image: example_results]

I want to obtain one max **price_count** value but only when count results are different e.g. in example below I should receive 120$ as result because it occured more times:

[image: example_results_2]

I don't have more ideas how my query should looks like so I need a little help.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Join the query with a query that counts the number of rows for each price count, and filters only returns counts with one row. If you're using MySQL 8.0 you can use a CTE to avoid repeating the query.

```
WITH counts AS (
    SELECT price_count, subquery.value
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(price_entity.value) price_count, price_entity.value
      FROM price_entity
               inner join purchasing_centre_entity pce on price_entity.purchasing_centre_id = pce.id
      where price_entity.purchasing_centre_id = 1
        and price_entity.product_id = 1
        and price_entity.create_date = DATE('2020-09-11')
      GROUP BY price_entity.value
     ) as subquery
)
SELECT c1.*
FROM counts AS c1
JOIN (
    SELECT price_count
    FROM counts
    GROUP BY price_count
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS c2 ON c1.price_count = c2.price_count
```